# Random Nginx rewrites for AB testing

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I would like to create an nginx rewrite from a location to multiple targets so i could do AB testing.

Something like:

```
rewrite ^/link/$ https://www.url1.com/ https://www.url2.com/ permanent;
```

When a visitor go to http://www.example.com/link/, it would send the same amount of visitors to url1.com and url2.com.

Thank you.

Comment: Are `url1.com` and `url2.com` completely separate web sites? Where are those web sites hosted? Using permanent redirects for A/B testing isn't a good idea, it confuses search engines.

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for the mistake. This would be files hosted on my server rewrite ^/link/$ file1.xml file2.xml;